# Multivariable vs single variable Alexander polynomial for links?

Tags: knot-theory, alexander-polynomial

If we take a $n$-component link $L$, we have the multivariable Alexander polynomial $\Delta(L)(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$. Is there a standard single-variable Alexander polynomial? If yes, is it just euqal to $\Delta(L)(t,\ldots,t)$?
I guess there is a normalized version in one variable that respects the skein relation.

Answer (score 3):

Both polynomials arise by considering the first homology of covering spaces of the link exterior $X_L$. If the link $L$ has $n$ components, then $\Delta_L(t_1,...,t_n)$ is extracted from the free abelian cover of $X_L$. The one variable polynomial comes from the infinite cyclic cover corresponding to the kernel of the map $\pi_1(X_L) \stackrel{ab}{\to} H_1(X_L)\to \mathbb{Z}$ that sends each meridian to $1$. The one variable version is for instance thoroughly discussed in Chapter 6 of Lickorish's "Introduction to knot theory". The relation $\Delta_L(t)\stackrel{.}{=}\Delta(t,...,t)(t-1)$ holds.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the one you get from HOMFLY polynomial. Recall that for the usual Conway triple $(L_+,L_-,L_0)$ HOMFLY polynomial $P$ has this relation:

$lP(L+)+l^{-1}P(L_-)+mP(L_0)=0$

Setting $l=i$ and $m=-i(t-t^{-1})$ would produce Alexander polynomial.

Also recall that Reshetikhin-Turaev construction of HOMFLY-equivalent polynomial family $\text{v}_n, n\ge2$ from $U_q(\mathfrak{su}(n))$ has this relation:

$q^n \text{v}_n(L_+)-q^{-n} \text{v}_n(L_-)=(q-q^{-1})\text{v}_n(L_0)$

$\text{v}_2$ happens to coincide with Jones polynomial, and $\text{v}_0$ is equivalent to the single-variable Alexander polynomial (after variable changes). Well, strictly speaking $v_0$ is not is not derived directly from  Reshetikhin-Turaev construction because of the lack of $\mathfrak{su}(0)$, but one can show that the case of $n=0$ follows from the validity of $v_n,n\ge2$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a one-variable polynomial. In fact, in my understanding, this came earlier than the multi-variable version.

Gwénaël Masseyeau has some [notes](http://massuyea.perso.math.cnrs.fr/notes/Alex.pdf) on the subject, with references to work of Conway (for the Conway polynomial and skein relations), Kauffman (for fixing Conway's approach in the single-variable case), and Hartley (for the multi-variable case). Right before Example 2.10 he has the identity you're looking for.